# NuGet publish 404 Not Found - VSTS Build

Tags: http-status-code-404, publish, nuget-package, azure-pipelines

Got lost with my VSTS CI build which stoped working overnight with a random **404 error message**:

```
[debug]   C:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_293.config
[command]C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\... C:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_293.config
Using credentials from config. UserName: VssSessionToken
Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
```

... and further the **failed publisher result**:

[image]

```
[debug]rc:1
[debug]success:false [debug]rm -rf C:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_293.config
[error]Error: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\... failed with return code: 1
[error]Packages failed to install
[debug]task result: Failed [error]Return code: 1
```

Twelve hours ago the Publisher task reported **success**:

```
[debug]   C:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_285.config
[command]C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\... C:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_293.config
Using credentials from config. UserName: VssSessionToken
Your package was pushed.
```

A ran the build multiple times with the same result. **Any idea what is going on?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this was an issue of VSTS and was resolved; presumably by Microsoft. I just had to wait some hours and the problem disappeared.